# Sharepoint - Link to a file that is updated Dynamically?

Tags: excel, pdf, sharepoint

I'm hoping this is possible. 
The organization I work for has a Sharepoint site and I am able to Upload Files to pages, however I am not an admin on our Sharepoint. I'm not sure what the version is, I think its older (ie: 2005).

I have some Excel Reports I've built.  The data for these reports is pulled from a SQL Server Database which I have full control over. I have setup a Job in SQL Server to run every 12 minutes, this procedure pulls in some data and updates a few tables. These tables are used to feed my Excel Reports.

I have a separate Scheduled task set to open my excel report(s) refresh the data connections and save as a PDF.

I would like to link to these PDF Files via our Sharepoint so that the VIPs can access the reports as they want, but they always see the most up to date report.

I was trying to link to a Shortcut to the PDF Files but SharePoint doesn't seem to like that. How do I make the SharePoint link point to the PDF File that is saved over every 15 minutes?

Thanks in advance,
Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this for?

Comment: I'm not sure but I am told it is old...2005?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it (newish version of Sharepoint) is make the save location for the PDF the network location where Sharepoint keeps the files for that site. Usually you'll have access to those if you can edit the Sharepoint site.

[Here](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/12/unc-path-naming-for-files-stored-on-sharepoint-2/) is a tutorial to find that network location.

EDIT: It very well may be disabled by the admin at the moment. But it looks like the functionality is [there](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2423797).

Comment: Thanks for this, I don't think I'm able to do this in our version of Sharepoint.  I did a bit more digging and it sounds like I need to get the admin to add the option to 'Link to Document' instead of 'Upload Document'...does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Given the age of your SharePoint (either 03 or 07), most of the modern tools that you could use to do this don't exist for you (Excel reporting, BI tools, etc). The easiest solution I can think of is to actually modify the other side of the equation. A few options:

- Change your report to output two copies of the same file. One entitled (as an example) currentreport.xls and the other report20150626.xls . Put the link to the currentreport.xls in SharePoint.
- Build an [ASP.net page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx) that runs the SQL query you have built and pull the data through a view. Since this would be pulled on demand, it may be a few more cycles of your SQL code, but indexing, caching and selective data pull can prevent this from being an issue. Put the asp.net code in an iFrame in a SharePoint content editor web part.
- Build your report using SSRS and host the output of that in SharePoint using an iFrame.
- Run a scheduled job in SQL that copies your current report data to a table and query that table instead of your normal report table. That way you only have one Excel file that points to a specific table so no need to update links. You can always keep copying data to specific files if you need a historical record and can't use the DB to store this data for you (though the amount of space that it would take to do so would be minimal).